# How to run a job only once a MR gets merged and know what MR got merged?

Tags: gitlab-ci, merge-request

I'm trying to run a GitLab pipeline job to move a Trello card to a different list, when the corresponding MR gets merged, but the job needs the MR's IID, to fetch its description, which contains the card ID.

On a [merge request pipeline](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/merge_request_pipelines.html), I can get the MR's IID from the `CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID` env var, but merge request pipelines run when MRs are created/updated, not when they get merged.

This is the way I found to make the job run only when a MR gets merged:

```yaml
move-card-to-done:
    stage: trello
    image: $MY_TRELLO_INTEGRATION_IMAGE
    tags:
        - docker
    only:
        - main
    when: on_success
    script:
        - moveCardToList $DONE_LIST_ID
```

The problem is that, since this is not a MR pipeline, the [predefined variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html#predefined-variables-for-merge-request-pipelines) I need are not available.
By printing all available env vars, the only reference to the MR I found was in `CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE`, but since this is customizable, there's no guarantee about its content.

This seems like a legitimate use-case. Isn't there a reliable way to do this?

Comment: There is https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/merged_results_pipelines.html which is a type of merge request pipeline so the `CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID` would likely still be available in it. However this is a premium and ultimate feature and not available on community edition

Comment: My understanding is that merged results pipelines run on open MRs (just like the other MR pipelines), so that you can test the code that would result from merging the MR, without actually merging it.

Comment: Ah yeah I see what you mean. No idea then